# Alert when I receive an email from a certain sender in my Gmail account

Tags: windows, chrome, gmail, notification

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension or Windows 7 program that can trigger a visual, hard-to-miss notification whenever I receive an email from a certain sender (defined by a specific email address) to my Gmail account. Free is better, I don't mind if not open source.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Chrome Desktop Notifications](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?hl=en)?

Comment: @AllanAlbright thanks but AFAIK we can only "turn desktop notifications on or off", we cannot configure the notification for a specific sender only.

Comment: You could set it up where you only get notified of emails marked as important and have the emails from that sender always get marked as important, but that's assuming you don't have any other emails that get marked as important.

Comment: Thanks good to know, but yeah in my case messages from other senders get marked as important too (also I don't use the priority inbox).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can tweak the specifics, but I'd use gmail, IFTT and pushbullet to do different parts of this.

You can set [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/) to trigger off an action on a channel on a message from a specific email address on gmail.

[image: enter link description here]

I'd use [pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)'s chrome extention or the desktop app to trigger off a notification on your PC though you can pick something else - even some web enabled devices, or even a phonecall in some locations.